# Pros and cons of different MKL algorithms

Tags: machine-learning, svm, kernel-trick

I have been using multiple kernel learning (MKL) to train a classifier and got some exposure to the field. However, I am quite new to machine learning and I have only an intuitive understanding of the subject. I have recently been told that the MKL algorithm I am using might not be the best choice for what I am trying to do, which leads to my question:

How do you go about choosing the best algorithm for the job - say for example [SimpleMKL](http://www.jmlr.org/papers/volume9/rakotomamonjy08a/rakotomamonjy08a.pdf), AverageMKL or [EasyMKL](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0925231215003653)? What is the intuition in the difference between these and what is the "ideal" application for each?

Comment: Can you define what MKL is?

Comment: @Sycorax yes, I am mean multiple kernel learning (MKL) as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62093700/12268981

Comment: Ok, in that case you'll need to explain what `SimpleMKL`, `AverageMKL` and `EasyMKL` are and where they come from. Are they part of some software package? Is this terminology used in some academic literature?

Comment: I have linked out the two original papers on SimpleMKL and EasyMKL in the question. Unfortunately, I struggle to understand them as my understanding is too intuitive for the depth they go into - hence why I was asking the question. AverageMKL is one of the options provided on MKLpy (https://github.com/IvanoLauriola/MKLpy1), but I could not find any formal literature on it.